# Rich Text Editor Error Messages

Tags: 2007, web-part, rich-text

My SharePoint system is experiencing problems when users attempt to edit a web-part text using the Rich Text Editor.

Upon selecting "Edit" from the web-part and clicking the "Rich Text Editor" button displayed in the Web-Part configuration pane the user is immediately presented a message dialog:

---

### Message from webpage

### Cannot retrieve properties at this time.

### OK

When the OK button is chosen on the dialog the HTML Editor window displays and appears normal.    The user is then able to enter text as normal but upon saving the user is then present another dialog:

---

### Message from webpage

### Cannot save your changes.

### OK

When the user clicks OK the page freezes up.

I have been unsuccessful in trying to fix this and am really looking for some help in fixing.  All ideas and suggestions are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First thing i would do is check your AAMs, if these are setup wrong, you will get this error.

If your AAMs are definitely setup right, you may still get this error with certain combinations of HTTPS, ports, load balancers and reverse proxies.

The rich text editor sometimes doesn't obey all the AAM rules and outputs bad postback/ajax urls, that you have fix them with a HttpModule. Use a response filter to fix the html before its delivered to the client. Some example code.

```
public class HTTPModule : IHttpModule {
    public override void Init(HttpApplication app) {
        base.Init(app);
        app.PostReleaseRequestState += new EventHandler(app_PostReleaseRequestState);
    }
    private void app_PostReleaseRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Page page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        if (response.ContentType.StartsWith(@"text/html")) {
            response.Filter = new PageFilter(response.Filter);
        }
    }
}

public class PageFilter : Stream {
    Stream responseStream;
    StringBuilder responseHtml;
    //todo: capture stream
    public override void Close() {
        responseHtml = Regex.Replace(responseHtml, "http://badurl", "http://goodurl", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        byte[] data = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(finalHtml);
        responseStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseStream.Flush();
        responseStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me in the past and the root cause was due to a CEWP imposing some bad CSS on the page.  Try closing out some of your rendered web parts to find the one causing the issue.

Comment: I've seen something similar before too. If closing or deleting web parts doesn't do it, it could be a change in the master page.

Comment: My issue seems to be related to the Load Balancer.  If I navigate directly to the front-end web the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

A work-around is to give the appropriate people designer rights to the Master Page Gallery. I've found the same work-around works for people that get access denied when trying to edit reusable content pages.